# Adding a directory to PATH to run scripts from subdir

Tags: shell, environment-variables, path

I'm using Ubuntu and I'm trying to add a folder to my `PATH` that contains subfolders including my scripts.

My folder paths are:

`/opt/tools/utils/my_script.sh`

`/opt/tools/steps/my_script.sh`

Other scripts do exist, but my focus is on `my_script.sh`

I have a script, clone from a repo, that does:
`export PATH=$PATH:/opt/tools`, and then it calls `utils/my_script.sh`.
This works fine on my machine, but on my coworker's machine it shows that `utils/my_script.sh` is not a file or directory. How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: I don't think that `utils/my_script.sh` would work even after adding `/opt/tools` to `$PATH`. What I think is that you are running `utils/my_script.sh` in the directory that contains `utils` directory. Can you show output of `ls -Al` and `pwd` done in the directory where you run `utils/my_script.sh`?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what the problem is you are having. I think if you succeed in describing your problem more clearly then the solution of the problem will fall out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `PATH` works. If I add a parent directory, I cannot simply call the child:

```
$ cat ~/foo/bin/bar.sh 
#!/bin/sh 
echo yeh!
```

Now, if I add `~/foo` to my `PATH`, I can't call the script with `bin/bar.sh`:

```
$ PATH="~/foo:$PATH"
$ bin/bar.sh
bash: bin/bar.sh: No such file or directory
```

I can only do that if I'm already in `~/foo`:

```
$ cd ~/foo/
$ bin/bar.sh
yeh!
```

The correct way to make the files in a directory available, is to add the directory itself to `PATH`, not just the directory's parents:

```
PATH="~/foo/bin:$PATH"
```

Now, I can call `bar.sh` from wherever:

```
$ cd /
$ bar.sh
yeh!
```

In other words, it isn't working on your machine either. You just must have run `utils/my_script.sh` from `/opt/tools`. Try `cd /` and then `utils/my_script.sh` and you'll see it fails for you as well.

Comment: This was actually the case. I tried what you said and it indeed failed. This led me to find the error and now I'm able to fix it. Thanks!